# Finding missing records in joined tables using ID and Dates in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I'm having trouble writing a check that will find missing records.

My tables are Provider, ProviderRelationship, Agreement, and AgreementProvider. I need to find missing records where the Provider has a ProviderRelationship, but no record for AgreementProvider for that specific time frame.

Both ProviderRelationship and AgreementProvider have StartDate and EndDate fields. Providers can only have 1 current ProviderRelationship, but they can have multiple ProviderRelationship entries. For example, ProviderA has ProviderRelationship1 on 3/17/2019, then ProviderRelationship2 from 3/18/2019 to 6/30/2020 and AgreementProvider2 for the same dates.

The closest I've come is this, which gets Providers that have never had any AgreementProvider entries at all. When I add in the date validation, it also includes the previous ProviderRelationships.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Provider
ProviderID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
Name VARCHAR(200) NULL
```

```
ProviderID    Name
9003055       ABC
6102          DEF
2743          Desired
9999          Ideal
```

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.ProviderRelationship
ProviderRelationshipID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
ParentProviderID INT NOT NULL,
ProviderID INT NOT NULL,
StartDate DATE NOT NULL,
EndDate DATE NOT NULL
```

```
ProviderRelationshipID  ParentProviderID  ProviderID  StartDate    EndDate
1                       9003055           9003055     2017-03-01   2017-03-27 --providers who are the parent provider should not appear
2                       1021              9003055     2017-03-27   2017-03-27
3                       1021              9003055     2017-03-28   2100-01-01 --should not appear
4                       184               6102        2015-07-01   2015-07-01
5                       6102              6102        2015-07-02   2100-01-01
6                       244               2743        2015-07-01   2100-01-01 --there is no AgreementProviderID record for this one
7                       1234              9999        2018-08-01   2019-09-01
8                       4321              9999        2019-10-01   2100-01-01 --this is the ideal result, since there is a gap in AgreementProvider records
```

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Agreement
AgreementID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
ProviderID INT NULL, --this is the ParentProviderID
RefRegionID INT NULL
```

```
AgreementID   ProviderID
1             1021
2             1021
3             184
4             184
5             184
6             184
7             244
8             244
9             244
10            1234
11            4321
```

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.AgreementProvider
AgreementProviderID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
AgreementID INT NULL,
ProviderID INT NULL,
StartDate DATE NULL,
EndDate DATE NULL
```

```
AgreementProviderID  AgreementID  ProviderID  StartDate     EndDate
1                    1            9003055     2017-03-28    2020-06-30
2                    2            9003055     2017-03-28    2020-06-30
3                    10           1234        2018-08-01    2020-06-30
```

```
SELECT DISTINCT o.*
FROM Provider p
JOIN dbo.ProviderRelationship prel ON prel.ProviderID = p.ProviderID
JOIN dbo.Agreement a ON a.ProviderID = prel.ParentProviderId
JOIN dbo.AgreementProvider ap ON ap.AgreementID = a.AgreementID
WHERE prel.ProviderID <> prel.ParentProviderId
AND p.ProviderID NOT IN (SELECT ap2.ProviderID FROM dbo.AgreementProvider ap2
       JOIN dbo.ProviderRelationship prel2 ON prel2.ProviderID = ap2.ProviderID
       WHERE prel.ParentProviderId = prel2.ParentProviderId)
```

It should not compare the date to a previous date, so ProviderID 9003055 should not appear. It should also not consider ProviderID when the ParentProviderID matches. It should get both Desired and Ideal ProviderIDs: Desired does not have a record, and Ideal does not have a current record for the current ProviderRelationship.

How would I rewrite this to include the specific time frame for each ProviderRelationship compared to the AgreementProvider information for those dates?

Ideal output would be this:

```
ProviderID    ParentProviderID     RelationshipStartDate     RelationshipEndDate
2743          244                  2015-07-01                2100-01-01
9999          4321                 2019-10-01                2100-01-01
```

Maybe it's already doing what I want, because there are invalid entries for the ProviderIDs that I don't want included. Maybe this is good enough, I will have to confirm.

Comment: Without table definitions this is pretty difficult. But for this type of thing you would typically use a NOT EXISTS as an additional where clause predicate. Sample data and desired output would be a huge step forward. Also a [mcve] would be useful.

Comment: And you may find some help in the answers to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325933/determine-whether-two-date-ranges-overlap

Comment: @SeanLange the tables are joined correctly. I need help with the coding to differentiate between sets of dates that already coincide with each other.

Comment: OK. But without some sample data I don't understand what you mean at all. Provide enough sample data to demonstrate what you want and tell us what the output should be for that sample data.

Comment: @SeanLange okay, I added my example records. But I noticed when entering them that maybe it's already doing what it should be. Will have to confirm.